# JSON Self referencing loop explanation

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-ajax, jquery

I am doing some work with C#, AJAX and JSON and am getting a Self referencing loop error. I am managing to get around this using the JsonIgnore attribute, but I was wondering if someone can give me a proper explanation as to what is actually happening here.

Many thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't get much detail on your problem, but it's probably exactly what you're describing: a loop of self-reference, or a circular chain of references.

Say you've got a variable of the type `User` that has a property `public UserImage Image`. Now, say the type `UserImage` has a property `User` that references back to the user.

In your .NET code, it's just that. `myImage.User` gives yo uthe user, `myUser.Image` gives you the image. But imagine you want to serialize `myUser` (into JSON, say). Then you have to cycle every property of `User` and serialize *that*, recursively. The serializer would start off like this

```
{ "ID": 1, "Image": { ...
```

now it has to serialize the user image. And remember `UserImage` has the variable "User".

```
{ "ID": 1, "Image": { "Path": "image.src", "User": {
```

but the user is the very same user that we're trying to reference

```
{ "ID": 1, "Image": { "Path": "image.src", "User": { "ID": 1, "Image":
```

now we have to serialize the image for *that* user, but that, again, is the same image as before:

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Image": {
    "Path": "image.src",
    "User": {
      "ID": 1,
      "Image": {
        "Path": "image.src",
        "User": {
          "ID": 1,
          "Image": {
            "Path": "image.src",
            "User": {
              "ID": 1,
              "Image": {
                "Path": "image.src",
                "User":
```

so we never reach an end product if we're constantly serializing a circular reference.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for, just a simple explanation of what is actually going on. Many thanks.